# Issue with D3 multi-line chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Hello I am trying to build a multi-line chart that displays rates for each month year over year.  I am getting a "TypeError: t is undefined" error in the console and while I can see the x and y axis populated, no lines are appearing in the chart. Any help appreciated!

The HTML file code is here:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>

 body {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
 }

 .axis path,
 .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }

 .x.axis path {
   display: none;
 }

 .line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 1.5px;
 }

 </style>
 <body>
 <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script>

 var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
     width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


 var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

 var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

 var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#666666", "#262626", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

 var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis").x(function(d) { return x(d.date); }).y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 d3.json("yoy_values.json", function(error, data) {
   if (error) throw error;

   var myValues = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; });

     data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.rates = myValues.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
        console.log(d.rates);

     });

   x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));


 y.domain([
     d3.min(data,   function(d) { return d3.min(d.rates, function(d) { return d.value; }); }),
     d3.max(data,   function(d) { return d3.max(d.rates, function(d) { return d.value; }); })
     ]);

   svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .call(xAxis);

   svg.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
       .call(yAxis)
     .append("text")
       .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
       .attr("y", 6)
       .attr("dy", ".71em")
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .text("Rates");

   var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
       .data(myValues.slice().reverse())
     .enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "state")
       .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

   state.append("path")
       .attr("class", "line")
       .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.rates); })
       .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

   state.append("text")
       .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.rates[d.rates.length - 1]}; })
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value) + "," + y(d.name) + ")"; })
       .attr("x", 3)
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
 });

 </script>
```

The JSON file I am reading looks like this:

```
[
    {"date":"Jan","2014":"0.0812","2015":"0.0780","2016":"0.0838"},
    {"date":"Feb","2014":"0.0806","2015":"0.0768","2016":"0.0893"},
    {"date":"Mar","2014":"0.0858","2015":"0.0847","2016":null},
    {"date":"Apr","2014":"0.0848","2015":"0.0889","2016":null},
    {"date":"May","2014":"0.0890","2015":"0.0890","2016":null},
    {"date":"Jun","2014":"0.0928","2015":"0.0865","2016":null},
    {"date":"Jul","2014":"0.0857","2015":"0.0799","2016":null},
    {"date":"Aug","2014":"0.0905","2015":"0.0845","2016":null},
    {"date":"Sep","2014":"0.1003","2015":"0.0934","2016":null},
    {"date":"Oct","2014":"0.0971","2015":"0.0993","2016":null},
    {"date":"Nov","2014":"0.0912","2015":"0.0973","2016":null},
    {"date":"Dec","2014":"0.0800","2015":"0.0777","2016":null}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from just code eyeballing, but I noticed:

1. You make a series of .rates properties from the non-"date" json data, so .rates for the first datum would be `[{name:"2014", value:"0.0812"},{name:"2015", value:"0.0780"},{name:"2016", value:"0.0838"}]`

   `d.rates = myValues.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });`
2. You then pass these to a d3.svg.line function

   `.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.rates); })`
3. But this line function has been previously set up to seemingly expect .date and .value properties not .name and .value

   `var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis").x(function(d) { return x(d.date); }).y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });`
4. And the scale x has been set up to expect .date (the month strings) as arguments, because they were set as the domain

   `x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));`

In short, it seems the x scale and line function are expecting data objects categorised by month to draw one line per year, but you're passing in the .rates objects which are organised by year in the expectation of drawing one line per month?